# Celebration: using anniversaries to open and publicize DSP topics

Tags: discussion, on-topic, asking-questions

We are celebrating in France the 250th anniversary of [Joseph Fourier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Fourier), who is relatively little known as a mathematician. He had many activities, including being a Prefect (Governor), published little but a book on the heat theory [(The analytical heat theory](https://www.britannica.com/topic/The-Analytical-Theory-of-Heat) at E. Britannica, and a [translation with notes](https://www3.nd.edu/~powers/ame.20231/fourier1878.pdf)). There barely is  a street name, and meanwhile JPEG or MP3 are directly related, possibly there is a 30% to 50% chance that every-time a computer runs an FFT.

I would be interested in asking a question about Fourier theory, and its interpretation, open questions, and most important messages. But this could become opinion-based quite quick. So:

**How appropriate would it be to ask generic questions using celebrations, anniversaries, at the risk of becoming opinion-based?**

Additional links (mostly French)

- [FOURIER 250](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/patrick.flandrin/Fourier250/index.html)
- [Fourier today](https://www.sciencesmaths-paris.fr/fr/maths-en-mouvement-2018-949.htm)

Comment: Appropriateness is typically subjective,  so are you asking for opinions on asking for opinions?

Comment: Neither, I asking for opinions instead. Seriously when an unseen occasion appears, one may ask whether it did not appear before. I believe that anniversaries are nice opportunities to glue the community

Comment: Can’t be neither. I don’t think there is a right or wrong answer. If you post something, I will not vote to close it as being off topic. If I were Egyptian, I might have mixed feelings about some who invaded my country.